# "Was he not doing his homework" vs " Wasn't he doing his homework"

Tags: negation

What is the difference between them.It is in a test  so I have no context.

> Was he not doing his homework
>
> Wasn't he doing his homework

Answer (score 1):

To me it sounds that the question

> Was he ***not*** doing his homework?

is asking whether "he" was *slacking off*, *ignoring* his *responsibility* to do his homework.  When spoken, the "*not*" would be emphasized.

The question

> *Wasn't* he doing his homework?

is intended to express doubt or request a confirmation.  The speaker supposes the "*he*" (the subject of the question) *was* in fact "*doing his homework*", but something in the conversation prior to this question presented a contrary view.

Answer (score 1):

I'll go out on a limb and take a different stance from other answers (that were posted before mine).

The only two differences between *Was he not doing his homework?* and *Wasn't he doing his homework?* are: a) the former is **an uncontracted negative question** (and the latter is a contracted negative question); and thus b) the former (*Was he not ...?*) would sound more formal.

Both alternatives can have either of these two meanings:

> [i] Is it true that *he wasn't doing his homework*?
>   [ii] It's true that *he was doing his homework*, isn't it?

The ambiguity is normally not a problem because it'd be clear in context.

In my humble opinion, there isn't any difference in meaning between the two written sentences out of context. We simply cannot assign a specific meaning to each alternative out of context.

Answer (score 1):

Most often, the two sentences can be used interchangeably.  They mean the same thing essentially, except the first sentence has no contraction and so is more formal.

The only reason the word order is different is due to the contraction "wasn't" (was not). It's a common and handy word that is used frequently, even in places where its un-contracted meaning "was not" would sound strange.

Nobody ever says "Was not he doing his homework?" but because of custom and habit, English speakers freely say "Wasn't he doing his homework?".  It's a quirk of the language.

This is not to say that the other answers are wrong, only that in everyday usage the speaker or writer is most likely not being that precise.

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence is asking if he was ***not doing*** his homework.

The second one refers to if he was ***doing*** his homework at the time.

Quite opposite to each other!

Comment: I am not sure I got it, can you explain it in some scenarios please if possible

Answer (score 0):

What Nihilist_frost says is true to an extent, but depending on the context the first first version could be a somewhat stuffy version of the second IMO.

Consider:

> Was he not doing his homework at the time?

This sentence sounds grammatically fine to me and leaves me in little doubt whoever is asking believe "he" was doing his homework at the time.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with most of the answers posted by the users.

"Was he not doing his homework?" and "Wasn't he doing his homework?" are 
syntactically similar, as "wasn't" (from the second sentence) is merely a contraction of "was not" (from the first sentence).

However, if we decipher the similarities and/or differences in the light of Semantics, the two statements have varying meanings.

First, the statement "Was he not doing his homework?" stresses on the "not doing" verb phrase of the sentence. Thus, this would mean that a person is asking another if "he" is "not doing" "his homework". We could paraphrase this as (although there is a difference in form) "He is *not doing* his homework, is he?"

Second, the statement "Wasn't he doing his homework?" emphasizes on "doing" or (could be) on "doing his homework". Therefore, this could mean that a person is asking another if "he" is **currently** working or not on "his homework". Another interpretation would be asking if "he" is (currently) working on **his own** homework. Since it is in the past tense, we could say that he *was currently working* on the homework mentioned.

I know that my explanation is somewhat confusing, but I hope this could give you more ideas regarding this topic.